# what is better: cast to double or adding double zero?

Tags: java, performance

Lets we have 4 `int` variables: `a, b, c, d`

and need to calculate `(a * b) / (c * d)`

There are 2 ways to do it:

1) `double result = ((double)(a * b)) / (c * d)`

2) `double result = (a * b) / (c * d + 0d)`

what are proc and cons for every of this ways?

Comment: 3) `double numerator = a * b; double denominator = c * d; double result = numerator / denominator;`.

Comment: Better? Casting is clearer.

Comment: I believe both ways force a cast to `double`... the `+ 0d` method has an additional add step (maybe)

Comment: When I first read `+ 0d`, it registered as `+ 0xD` in my brain.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `+ 0d` is another two bytecode instructions: get the zero, add the zero.

Comment: Wouldn’t the compiler be smart enough to skip the addition of 0 and only do the type conversion? Just guessing … Anyway, as @MikeDunlavey said, casting is clearer, that’s what should count.

Comment: "Wouldn’t the compiler be smart enough..." not when I tried :) but the JIT would.

Comment: @OleV.V.: The compiler will cast to double just before storing into `result`. It's not actually correct for it to do it any sooner.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey, I was being unclear. I meant in the `c * d + 0d` case. Obviously c * d will be calculated in integer arithmetic (with possibility of overflow), I was asking if the compiler would then only do the conversion to double and then see that adding 0d was unnecessary and hence skip it?

Comment: @OleV.V.: Understood. You're right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't mind my saying so, your ways are very bad indeed.

`(a * b)` is *still computed in integral arithmetic* so will suffer from wrap-around. (This merely confounds my belief that excess parentheses are a scaled down version of the devil.) In C and C++ it's far worse, the overflow behaviour is *undefined* and compilers reserve the right to eat your cat.

Worse than that, `c * d` is also evaluated in integer arithmetic in *both* cases! The *result* of this expression is converted to a `double`.

I believe that `1.0 * a * b / c / d` is the clearest way of writing this as `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are *all* promoted to `double` types prior to evaluation. My way specifies your intention from the get-go.

Answer (score 6):

One of the cleanest approaches here is relying on automatic promotion that happens in argument passing. Simply declare a method

```
double multiplyAndDivide(double a, double b, double c, double d) {
    return (a * b) / (c * d);
}
```

and call it as

```
return multiplyAndDivide(a, b, c, d);
```

Comment: Upvoted. That is remarkably pretty! I guess the expense is a plethora of functions with specific mandates. In non-scientific codebases (where clarity is very important)  I think I prefer this to my solution.

Comment: In Java, functions with specific mandates are the bread and butter :) It's not great, but I learned to accept it.

Comment: Out of interest, how does "lambdaing" this shake out in Java?

Comment: I was considering that as well, but you'd need a custom functional interface with four `double` arguments. I don't think it's worth it, unless you happen to have a whole bag of four-arg `double` functions.

Comment: Or, `divide(a * b, c * d)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner: how could you???!! `a*b` and `c*d` will suffer wrap around. See my answer.

Comment: @AndyTurner That wouldn't move you off the starting point, Cf. Bathsheba's answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba <sigh> I'll get my coat.

Comment: @AndyTurner But your idea inside-out would work! `return mul(a,b) / mul(c,d)`. A very special-case solution, though.

Comment: As would the absolutely wonderful `mul(mul(a, b), 1/mul(c,d))`. Muhahahahaha.

Comment: +1 The nice thing is here that you don't have to care about what to use: `(double) a * b / ...` (which is sufficient) or `(double) a * (double) b` (which is symmetrical) or whatever. It's also more readable